# Get ids of the products which a bundle product contains

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product

I need to get the id of each product which composes the bundle product.
There is this `foreach ($optionsArray as $_option)` in 
`public function getJsonConfig()` from \app\code\core\Mage\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle.php
I need for each product which is in the bundle I want to get a custom attribute.
I tried some solution but I am not able to get what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. I had to dig deeper in app\code\local\OSF\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle.php
I added in `function getJsonConfig()` my extra data which I needed.

Answer (score 4):

you get all bundle product ids by using below code

```
$childrenIdArray = Mage::getResourceSingleton('bundle/selection')
            ->getChildrenIds($parentId, $required=true);
```

Comment: hey, is its works?

Answer (score 1):

Look at method of class **Mage_Bundle_Helper_Catalog_Product_Configuration**

```
/**
 * Get bundled selections (slections-products collection)
 *
 * Returns array of options objects.
 * Each option object will contain array of selections objects
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getBundleOptions(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Configuration_Item_Interface $item)
{
    $options = array();
    $product = $item->getProduct();

    /**
     * @var Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type
     */
    $typeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance(true);

    // get bundle options
    $optionsQuoteItemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('bundle_option_ids');
    $bundleOptionsIds = $optionsQuoteItemOption ? unserialize($optionsQuoteItemOption->getValue()) : array();
    if ($bundleOptionsIds) {
        /**
        * @var Mage_Bundle_Model_Mysql4_Option_Collection
        */
        $optionsCollection = $typeInstance->getOptionsByIds($bundleOptionsIds, $product);

        // get and add bundle selections collection
        $selectionsQuoteItemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('bundle_selection_ids');

        $bundleSelectionIds = unserialize($selectionsQuoteItemOption->getValue());

        if (!empty($bundleSelectionIds)) {
            $selectionsCollection = $typeInstance->getSelectionsByIds(
                unserialize($selectionsQuoteItemOption->getValue()),
                $product
            );

            $bundleOptions = $optionsCollection->appendSelections($selectionsCollection, true);
            foreach ($bundleOptions as $bundleOption) {
                if ($bundleOption->getSelections()) {
                    $option = array(
                        'label' => $bundleOption->getTitle(),
                        'value' => array()
                    );

                    $bundleSelections = $bundleOption->getSelections();

                    foreach ($bundleSelections as $bundleSelection) {
                        $qty = $this->getSelectionQty($product, $bundleSelection->getSelectionId()) * 1;
                        if ($qty) {
                            $option['value'][] = $qty . ' x ' . $this->escapeHtml($bundleSelection->getName())
                                . ' ' . Mage::helper('core')->currency(
                                    $this->getSelectionFinalPrice($item, $bundleSelection)
                                );
                        }
                    }

                    if ($option['value']) {
                        $options[] = $option;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $options;
}
```